# Storing Database Credentials in Cakephp 3.1 app.php file

Tags: php, cakephp, file-permissions

I'm putting the finishing touches on my cakephp project (configuring final database grants, etc) and realised something about cakephp.

From what I can tell (unless I inadvertently changed it), cakephp shipped with the app.php file permissions of -rw-rw-r-- (662).

Doesn't allowing anyone with access to the server the ability to see your database credentials pose a security risk?

Would it break things if I changed this to -rw-------? (600)

Comment: almost all files on Linux have read permissions to everyone on them. if your server is breached it's breached wipe it start again, also your DB login should be secured to the server the login is coming from far more chance of some one exploiting php to damage your DB than some one hacking your server to damage your database

Comment: Formatting and quality of grammar in the question. has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally depends on your configuration, there is no one correct way to do it, so `-rw-rw-r--` aka `0664` is likely just fine. If your web server process runs under the same user that owns the files then `-rw-------` aka `0600` is ok. But generally, you want to *ensure that the web server process does not have write permission to the files it serves*. You can achieve this purely with file permissions but I prefer to make the user that runs the web server process different than the user that owns the files being served.